# Add shp attribute data to column with python script

Tags: arcpy, cursor

If feature column (feature is the name of the column) in table is ferry crossing in the attribute data then I need to add Yes to the Ferry column that I have already added to the table.

If the feature column does not say ferry crossing I need to add No to the ferry column. Here is a code snippet that I am having an issue with.

I'm new to python.

```
#need to update FERRY column with yes or no values if ferry crossing is available in feature field
delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, "FERRY")
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FERRY"])
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] == "ferry crossing":
        cursor.updateRow("FERRY")
        print "YES"
    if row[0] is not "ferry crossing":
        cursor.updateRow("FERRY")
        print "NO"

del row
del cursor

#if feature is ferry crossing == YES in FERRY field
#if feature is not ferry crossing == NO in FERRY field
```

Comment: I think you should compare your code against the examples at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm  Are you really planning to overwrite the value "ferry crossing" in the `FERRY` field with "YES" in the same field.  What happens when you run the exact code snippet that you have presented here?  Any error messages should be included along with the code snippet.

Comment: Polygeo I want yes or no added to the ferry field that I have created through python programming that isn't included here. The feature column that says ferry crossing in about half the records should stay the same.

Comment: Then Aaron's answer should do just what you are after.

Comment: Cross post from http://stackoverflow.com/q/35247335/820534

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would encourage you to follow the more modern [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) syntax. The following script should get you started. In this example, There are two fields "field1" and "FERRY". If "ferry crossing" is in "field1", the "YES" will be added to the "FERRY" field, otherwise "NO".

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\feature_class'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["field1", "FERRY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "ferry crossing":
            row[1] = "YES"
        else:
            row[1] = "NO"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: that was right, thanks. I did have to update with the actual column name for field1 and change out ferry crossing for Ferry Crossing as it was written in the attribute table but all is well. Aaron you rock!